# denormalized scheme for authorization handling

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, authorization

Please, feel free to comment and share any feedback to help me find a solution. Thanks !

This is the authorization table defining the scope of each user.
I currently don't know **how to scope data at the `product` level** and handle the different roles. I believe my **database schema is wrongly setup**.

`C` Create, `R` Read, `U` Update, `D` Delete

[image]

I have the following database structure with **postgresql 9**

1) `user` table `has_many` entries inside `stores` table.

```
-----------------------------
| id  | org_tag  |  email   |
|---------------------------|
|  1  |    a     | a@em.com |
|---------------------------|
|  2  |    b     | b@em.com |
|---------------------------|
|  3  |    c     | c@em.com |
-----------------------------
```

2) `stores` table includes a `jsonb` column `employees`, the `user_id` and the `tags` array column

The `store` owner can add `employees` to the store which will have special `authorization` grants depending on the `role`.

I filter the store based on the `tags` array to `scope` the data and handle the authorization.

```
----------------------------------------------
| id  | user_id  |  employees  |     tags     |
|---------------------------------------------|
|  1  |    1     |  see json1  |  ['a', 'b']  |
|---------------------------------------------|
|  1  |    1     |  see json2  |  ['a', 'c']  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

The `json1` value is

```
[{'email':'a@em.com','role':'owner'},{'email':'b@em.com','role':'trial_editor'}]
```

The `tags` corresponds to the `user.org_tag`

The `json2` value is

```
[{'email':'a@em.com','role':'owner'},{'email':'c@em.com','role':'manager'}]
```

3) `products` table

The `trial product editor` can only edit the product he was assigned to.
I can scope the `product`s by `tags`, but I don't know how to handle different `roles`

For Ex. The **Store Manager** can create products, while the `Trial Product Editor` can only read and update.

```
--------------------------------
| id  | user_id  |    tags     |
|------------------------------|
|  1  |    1     | ['a', 'b']  |
|------------------------------|
|  1  |    1     | ['a', 'c']  |
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be too parsimonious with tables.  You seem to need:

- `employees` with one row per employee
- `storeEmployees` with one row per store per employee (assuming employees can be in more than one store)
- `storeEmployeeTags` with one row per store/employee/tag

Implementing one many-to-many relationship using arrays can be a reasonable choice.  You have multiple such relationships so I would suggest that you implement the data model more in tables than arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll will try to be more active on StackOverflow and contribute for the help I received

Answer (score 0):

User

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id |  org_tag   |     email      |    org_handle   | 
------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     a      |  a@email.com   |       xyz       | 
------------------------------------------------------ 
|  2 |     b      |  b@email.com   |       xxx       |  
------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     c      |  c@email.com   |       abc       | 
------------------------------------------------------
```

Role

```
------------------------------------------------
| id  |  store_id  |  user_id  |    position   |
------------------------------------------------ 
|  1  |     1      |     1     |     owner     |
------------------------------------------------ 
|  2  |     1      |     2     |    manager    |
------------------------------------------------ 
|  1  |     2      |     2     |  trial_editor |
------------------------------------------------
```

Store

```
-----------------------------------
| id  |  employees  |  org_handle |
-----------------------------------
|  1  |  see json1  |     abc     |
-----------------------------------
|  2  |  see json2  |     xyz     |
-----------------------------------
```

The *employees* *jsonb* is:

```
[{'email':'a@em.com','role':'owner'},{'email':'b@em.com','role':'trial_editor'}]
```

Product

```
--------------------------------
| id  | store_id |   role_id   | 
--------------------------------
|  1  |     1    |      1      |
--------------------------------
|  2  |     2    |      2      |
--------------------------------
```

## Associations

```
Organization has_many :users
User has_many :stores, through: roles
User has_many :role
User belongs_to :organization
Role belongs_to :user
Role belongs_to :store
Role has_many :products
Store has_many :users, through: roles
Store has_many :roles
Store has_many :products
Product belongs_to :store
Product belongs_to :role
```